# Locating Special Tools for Auto Free Hub Removal

Tags: brake-rotor, tools, 4wd

I am attempting to replace rotors on a 1988 Dodge Ram 50 (2.6L, 4WD). To remove the rotors, I need to use a special socket (visible around the [auto free hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To5vh.jpg) ) and the special locknut socket. Are there any suggestions on where I might find these tools?

[image: Auto free hub]

Comment: Aren't those just Allen head bolts?

Comment: @Paulster2 : Your comment is half an answer. I presume the other "special socket" refers to the lug nuts. OP, please clarify if that isn't the case. I'd like to see this question out of the "Unanswered" category.

Answer (score 2):

The special tool you are requesting appears to be an allen drive.

They can be procured online by doing a google search for "allen drive socket"

[image]